# Home.php won't show whether I have logged in or not

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Help, probably a total noob question, but home.php won't show if I have logged in or not. Home.php is connected to the database, but I put the correct username and password details and all it says 'Please log in first Login. '

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username= '{$_SESSION['user']}'" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$ms);
if( !mysql_num_rows($result) ) die( 'Please log in first<a href="index.php">Login</a>'          );


echo "You are Welcome ". $_SESSION['user'];


?>

<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Where and how do you set `$_SESSION['user']`? Also `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: add `echo $sql . "\n" . mysql_error();` right after your `mysql_query()`

Comment: Why are you asking same question again and again?

Answer (score 1):

Check your query again for typos. Mark **table names** and **field names** with **`**.

Note that the `mysql_*` methods are deprecated. Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead.

Also check if your `$_SESSION` variable is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query seems to be wrong to me.

For a simple solution, try

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'";
```

BTW you're better off coding OO, employing best practices (SoC, MVC, patterns, etc.), sanitizing data and using prepared statements instead of such query buildups.

---

Also is `$_SESSION['user']` set at all?

*Note that `$_SESSION['user']` might as well be uninitialized*

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Are you sure the brackets are fine there?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct syntax for array variables or variable names containing "strange" characters in a string

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Hmm... I haven't seen such solution before. Gonna try that out once I have a few minutes.

Comment: Well I used the SQL query, it still shows the same as before.

Comment: @user2629684 add `echo mysql_error()` to your script as I suggested in my comment above and add the output to your question

Comment: @GeraldSchneider PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/koccucc/public_html/panel/home.php on line 6

Comment: @user2629684 add the line `if (!$result) die(mysql_error());` right after the query. That'll help a lot. (Never do that with production code though)

Comment: @user2629684 It should as `$result` is `null` indicating that an error occured. Also, I'm pretty sure you neglect to set `$_SESSION['user']` thus your query will always fail.

Comment: @user2629684 So, do you get any errors now? Or does it already work?

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username= '{$_SESSION['user']}'" ;
```

This line of code has error.
`{$_SESSION['user']}` store this value in one variable.

See this example:

```
$xyz= $_SESSION['user'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username= '$xyz'" ;
```

May be this will work for you.

Comment: This line is valid, no need to change it.

Comment: That is not true. You can use `{` and `}` to surround a variable in a string.

Comment: Consider amending your answer in view of the comments received.